# Is there a way, to bulk insert into SQL table, if the file, that contains the data is unformatted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First of all, hi!
So basically I have a bunch of data in a txt file (~1,5 million rows), and I would like to bulk insert it into an SQL table. The problem is, it only has 1 column and everything is in a new row. It looks something like this;

```
DateAndTime
  VarType = "xy"
  Data = "xy"|
Angle1
  VarType = "xy"
  Data = "xy"|
Angle2
  VarType = "xy"
  Data = "xy"
```

and so on.
In the table I created, my columns are "DateAndTime", "Angle1", "Angle2" etc. From the example I provided, I only need the name of the data (like "Angle1") as a column header, and the "Data". I'm totally lost, I've no clue what to do.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't `BULK INSERT` it; the design is terrible. Instead you'll want to use some kind of custom ETL process, maybe written in a .Net language, maybe using a CLI language, maybe something else entirely that you're more familiar with, to read the file and either normalise it, or create datasets within itself that are normalised and can be bulk inserted. You'll have a nightmare fixing your data in SQL Server and you have nothing that even tells you the correct order of the data, so it'll be utterly useless.

Comment: Re: "I'm totally lost, I've no clue what to do." - wrong attitude. I would start with preprocessing such data, there are certainly some unix-linux based commandline tools - few hours in google would help a lot :) Google would reveal more SQL options either.

Comment: You can process it in C# and use `SqlBulkCopy` from there

Comment: Tidy the data before importing. It may be easier to head for an XML or json data structure than something CSV-like, but then the import will be a little more difficult. My approach would vary depending upon whether this is a one-off task or something you're going to need to repeat. For a one-off, find a text editor with good RegEx and large file support and practice RegEx find/replace on a smaller version of the file first. Not a one off? Then  that still might be a useful first step, but then you want to turn those "manual steps" into a script for `sed`, `awk` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I know it's not really the right attitude, however this is my first larger "data science" project. I already made a lot of progress (I had to get the data, had to merge it etc.), but this seems like I hit a solid wall. As an intern, I don't really have that much experience, since I've never done anything like this before. By the way, how could I process it in C#? That's the CLI language I'm most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm biased toward SQL, so I would probably take the following approach:

1. Create a staging table that has an identity column.
2. Insert the rows into the table.
3. Process the table to get the results that you want.

(3) Is rather complicated, and I'm not 100% sure I understand the processing.  But the idea is:

- Assign a "record" value as a cumulative sum of `dateandtime` up to each row.
- Use `lag(-2)` to get the name for the data rows.
- Use conditional aggregation to get the final results.